# Must Login Twice before Successful Login

Tags: php

I have created a homepage where user has to login if user hasn't login.

Here is my `index.php` :

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['PHPSESSID'];
echo $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
require_once('config.php');
require_once('core/login.php');

$config = new Notesconfig();
$baseURL = $config -> baseURL;
$login = new Login();
$connect = $login -> connectDB($config -> host, $config -> user, $config -> password, $config -> db);

if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $login -> processLogin($connect, $_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']), $baseURL);
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $login -> processLogout($connect, $baseURL);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>/css/main.css">
</head>
<body class="mainBody">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['PHPSESSID']) || empty($_SESSION['PHPSESSID']) || !isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) || empty($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) || ($_SESSION['PHPSESSID']) != ($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
        ?>
            <div id="main-content" style="width: 960px;">
            <?php
                $login -> viewLoginForm();
            ?>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
            else {
        ?>
            <div id="main-content" style="width: 710px;">
            </div>
            <div id="right-column" style="width: 250px;">
                <a href="./?logout=true" class="logout" target="_self" >Logout</a>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `core/login.php` :

```
<?php

class Login {

    //Connect Database
    public function connectDB($host, $user, $password, $db) {
        $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);        //mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
        if($connect) {
            echo "Database Connection Established.";
            return $connect;
        }
        else {
            echo "Database Connection Failed.";
        }       
    }

    //Login User
    public function processLogin($connection, $username, $password, $baseURL) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, stripslashes($username));
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, stripslashes($password));
        $db = "SELECT `username`, `password`, `phpsessid` FROM `login` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password' LIMIT 1";

        $db_query = mysqli_query($connection, $db);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($db_query)) {
            echo "Query Success.";
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_query);
            $_SESSION['PHPSESSID'] = $row['phpsessid'];
            setcookie("PHPSESSID", $row['phpsessid'], 0);
        }
        else {
            echo "Query Failed. Reason:".$connection->error;
            return false;
        }
        mysqli_close($connection);
        header('Location: '.$baseURL);
        die;
    }

    //Logout User
    public function processLogout($connection, $phpsessid, $baseURL) {
        unset($_SESSION['PHPSESSID']);
        //unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
        setcookie("PHPSESSID", $phpsessid, time()-360000);
        mysqli_close($connection);
        header('Location: '.$baseURL);
    }

    //Display Login Form
    public function viewLoginForm() {   

        echo '<form action=" " id="loginForm" method="POST" >';
        echo '<table class="loginForm">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>Matric No.</td><td><input type=\"text\" name="username" /></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '</form>';

    }

}

?>
```

The `config.php` just contains some data I want to use :

```
<?php

class Notesconfig {

    public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/notes';
    public $siteName = 'Notes';
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $db = 'notes';

}

?>
```

However, I need to login twice then successfully set the `session` and `cookies`, while I don't need to logout twice.

When I clicked login for the first time, I get `Query Success`, but not login.

Then I clicked AGAIN the login, and this time I'll successfully login.

After login, I clicked logout, and I return to the login page. And again I need to login twice to successfully login.

How can I solve this error?

EDIT

Change all `PHPSESSID` and fix the problem.

Comment: adding removing cookies and sessions ... Why you don't just set 1 session user and remove it on logout ? Its a lot easier :)

Comment: Quick note: Change both `mysql_real_escape_string` to `mysqli_real_escape_string` - You're mixing both `MySQL_` and `MySQLi_`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting value from `$_COOKIE` in same request after setting it which is not possible. This value will be accessible from the next request so after logging in you have to redirect user (and it's good to redirect after `POST` request).

Comment: I have added the `header` into the `processLogin` function, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Chin Add `die;` after header and turn on error reporting `error_reporting(-1);`. Also check using firebug if cookie is really set after first login and redirect.

Comment: I updated my code. The `cookie` is set during first login, but not the `session`. During second login, `session` and `cookie` both set, and success. Logout successfully remove the `session` and change the `cookie` to "1381667986". Why first login the `session` is not set?

Comment: @Chin Remove all lines with `PHPSESSID`. PHP will set it automatically and while overwriting it in cookie you'll move user to another session (and that can cause problems).

Comment: That fixes it. Browser will create own `PHPSESSID` session and cookie?

Comment: @Chin No, PHP will create it and send to browser after `session_start()`.

Comment: I just have to use name other than `PHPSESSID` for the session only?

Comment: @Chin No, just don't set session cookie if you're using built-in sessions. Set what you need in `$_SESSION` and use it to get logged in user (PHP will automatically get user session data after starting session).

Comment: On a semi-related note (because I personally don't know), would a refresh be an equivalent measure for clearing POST?

Comment: @Rogue No, clearing POST will not change anything in request, only in data fetched from request (no difference for browser). Redirecting will change request method to GET (by performing new request) and prevent resending POST data again using F5.

Comment: Agree with @ElonThan. Refreshing will resend the data.